# Feathers - Socket.io - /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket - 404 not found

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, feathersjs

I get the following error `https://0.0.0.0:3030/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket 404 not found`.

I am using this code for my server side :

```js
// index.ts
import fs from "fs";
import https from "https";

const server = https
  .createServer(
    {
      cert: fs.readFileSync("server.crt"),
      key: fs.readFileSync("server.key"),
      requestCert: true,
      rejectUnauthorized: true,
      ca: fs.readFileSync("rootCA.crt")
    },
    app
  )
  .listen("3030");
```

And I am using this code for the client side :

```js
// feathers-client.ts
const socket = io("https://0.0.0.0:3030", {
  transports: ["websocket"],
  secure: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A socket.io client connects to a socket.io server.  The server code you show is only a plain web server.  You need the socket.io server library to hook into your web server so that it can handle incoming socket.io connections.  You can do that like this:

```
// index.ts
import fs from "fs";
import https from "https";
import socketIO from 'socket.io';

const server = https.createServer(
    {
      cert: fs.readFileSync("server.crt"),
      key: fs.readFileSync("server.key"),
      requestCert: true,
      rejectUnauthorized: true,
      ca: fs.readFileSync("rootCA.crt")
    },
    app
  )
  .listen("3030");

// hook socket.io into your server to make an instance of a socket.io server
const io = socketIO(server);
```

Now, your server is reading for incoming socket.io client connections with the client code you show.

Comment: @Pyth0nGh057 - Did this answer your question? If so, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.